# Error with pipe.stdin.write

Tags: python, pipe

I want to execute a Perl script using this Python code

```
def convert_to_excel(filename):
print('file name :' + filename)
pipe = subprocess.Popen(["perl", "./parse.pl", filename])
pipe.stdin.write(filename.encode('utf-8'))
pipe.stdin.close()
```

but I have this Error and this is my backtrace

```
file name :nessus_44_623890728.nessus
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/root/PycharmProjects/Nessus/main.py", line 317, in <module>
convert_to_excel('nessus_44_623890728.nessus')
File "/root/PycharmProjects/Nessus/main.py", line 268, in 
convert_to_excel
pipe.stdin.write(filename.encode('utf-8'))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Comment: But... you just passed the file name as the argument to your Perl script. Why'd you need to write it to Perl's `stdin`?

Comment: I write like this `subprocess.Popen(["perl", "parse_nessus_xml.v20.pl", filename])
` line but not work with me I don't know why, So I try this, Perl script work fine from terminal.